# Need to enable the button when all textbox has value in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app and want to implement the feature only to enable the submit button when all `required` textboxes, checkboxes, etc have value.

I can only think of one idea that in all controls' `changed` handler, I need to write conditions that all fields have value but it is tedious and surely think there is a nice way to do this. And I found many resources for WPF but not for UWP. So I came up here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no simple way could directly achieve your requirement. You could do it through data binding. First, you need to set public string property **Text1**,**Text2** and Boolean property **Enable**, **Checked** in code behind, then you could bind them to the corresponding property of element. So that you could set the **Enable** value through the property value that other controls passed to backend.

Please refer to the following.

Xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button x:Name="button" Content="Load" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{x:Bind Enable,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{x:Bind Text1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox2"  Text="{x:Bind Text2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind Checked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _enable;
    private string _text1;
    private string _text2;
    private bool _checked;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool Enable
    {
        get
        { return _enable;}
        set
        {
            if(value != _enable)
            {
                _enable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Enable");
            }               
        }
    }
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set
        {
            _text1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text1");
            UpdateButton();

        }
    }
    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _text2; }
        set
        {
            _text2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text2");
            UpdateButton();
        }
    }
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set
        {
            _checked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Checked");

            UpdateButton();           
 }
   }

    private void UpdateButton()
    {
        if (Text1 != string.Empty && Text2 != string.Empty && Checked == true)
        {
            Enable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Enable = false;
        }
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));

    }
    
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
       
    }

   
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how to display validation messages in form as well? I'm going to display to the controls' `description` and is it supposed to be?